# How to permanently delete a git repo which is cloned from git-bash?

Tags: windows-10, clone, git-bash

I am using Windows 10(64-bit). So I cloned a repository through git-bash in my home directory just for testing but when I have been done with that repo. I decided to delete that directory and successfully deleted but that repo reappeared again and again after some days. How is this possible? So below are the methods I already tried:-

- First one obviously, right clicked on repo and clicked on "Delete"
- With cmd:- `rmdir /s /q filename`
- In git-bash:- `rm -rf filename`

So all above methods worked but the strange thing is how it is reappearing and the most strange part is that git repo is not a repo now! Instead it is just a normal folder containing a sub folder named "Pictures" and which in turn contains "Saved Pictures" and "Camera Roll" that contains nothing.
This is the current directory structure:-

```
C:\Users\USER\ptf\Pictures
```

"ptf" was the name of git repo(Pentester's Framework)

So my question is:- Is anything similar happened to anybody and how to permanently delete that folder?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a windows user but if the option /r or /s remove recursively dthe subdirectories, you should verify that the .git hidden (in Linux) directory has been also deleted.
It's there that git stores all its info and maybe if .git is still present in your directory, you are still seeing the repo.

Comment: as I said in my question, now, that folder is not a git repository.